# How to get results back from union of 2 cte's based on parameters having different values IN SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, union, common-table-expression

I have to build a report where users want to see combined data from 2 disparate sources in SSRS. The report has some set of parameters. 
The set of parameters are common for both data sources.
I have 2 data sources A and B. I have written 2 cte's and then created a union between these 2 cte's. My question is if there is a way that we can get combined data from both cte's based on the individual parameter values which are different in both sources. To be more specific, for example I have 3 parameters @id, @name and @country.
Can't join bcz data is different in both sources.
Source A and B both have id, name, class,sales,country

**Code**

```
Create  Procedure [sp_1]
@id varchar(50),
@name varchar(max),
@country varchar(500)
As begin
;with cte1
As (select  * from A)

,cte2
As ( select * from B)

,ReportingData 
As(select * from A union select * from B)

select * from ReportingData
```

----This is the code structure---
the sp creates successfully.
Source A data

```
id , name , class, sales, country
1A     Sid     02     45    USA
2A    Amri     03     56     USA
```

Source B data

```
id , name , class, sales, country
1     Larry    02     45    USA
2     Amri    04    100    Aus
```

What I want to know  is if i pass

```
@id = 1A
@name = Amri
@Country = USA
```

to my sp will I get the combined results belonging to Amri ?

i.e. desired output

```
id, name, class, sales, country
2A  Amri   03      56      USA
2   Amri    04     100     Aus
```

Is this technically possible ?

Is there any workaround ?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: What is the purpose of the at id and at country parameter if it is returning everything for only Amri? as in at name??? Why would there be no filtering on id and country that are supplied as parameters?

Comment: You need to tell us more detail about three paramters logic

Comment: can you double-check that the expected result shown above is correct? it looks like name is the only parameter that matters

Comment: Ok, so t give more clarity. the data that i have is like that only i.e. id and country for both systems are different and the user should be able drive the report based on these 3 parameters as well as a source parameter.

Comment: given the parameter values that you desire to pass.. how can you logically arrive at the desired output? Can you explain?

Comment: Nope.. not with the given parameter values.. think logically.. you are asking for all records that have and id of '1A' that limits it to Sid from source A. then you are asking for name = 'Amri'.. at this point.. you get no records returned. as '1A' is not Amri.

Answer (score 0):

Just assuming you don't care about the other parameters, you have most of the code except for the where clause

```
Create  Procedure [sp_1]
@id varchar(50),
@name varchar(max),
@country varchar(500)
As begin
;with cte1
As (select  * from A)

,cte2
As ( select * from B)

,ReportingData 
As(select * from A union select * from B)



   select
     ReportingData.* 
       from ReportingData
         where ReportingData.Name = @name
```

so now if you pass 'Amri' as your name parameter value.. the stored procedure will return the desired result (as in your expected result)

If you need further filtering on the other parameters then you would just add then as as `and @id = id` etc'.,

Comment: Hi Harry,  Thanks for your response. So even if 1 parameter values differs and rest have same values for both sources, i should be able to get the combined result set . Is this a current assumption ?

Comment: @guest678 yes.. the parameter only filters on which column you ask it to filter on. in my query.. the where clause is only filtering on the Name and completely ignores the other parameters.. if you want to use the other parameters, you need to add an AND like I have mentioned in my answer

Comment: What will I get if I pass @id= 1A, @name= Amri, @Country= USA. , @Source= 'A,B'. There is one more parameter called source in my report to give the users te ability to select between sources either A or B or both and be able to see the data .

Comment: once you have joined the data in your CTE.. it doesn't matter what the source is.. you don't even mention @source in your original question! with the given parameter values.. you will get 0 records returned.

Comment: I apologise for not mentioning the source param in my original post. You are right I am getting 0 records returned. Is there no way that I can get data even if the parameter values in both sources don't match each other ?

Comment: The whole point of parameters is to pass a value and filter the data based on that parameter value. so again.. given the parameter values.. there is absolutely NO way you will arrive at your desired output.  unless you show some logic on why you think the desired result should be returned..